# where I can take ajax dropdown categories menu for laravel 5.1?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I need article to how creating ajax dropdown categories for laravel 5.1.
It would be nice if got rid of a lot of examples.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: Yes I have tried. But I haven't found normal ajax dropdown. I was trying to do by Google.

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field